# speed of elements that are loaded website php

Tags: javascript, php, html, pagespeed

I wondering about the following. 
I know it is possible to check the loading speed of our website with for example.

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);

  //your script here

$end = microtime(true);
$time = $end - $start;
echo('script took ' . $time . ' seconds to execute.');
?>
```

Is there also a way to check the loading speed of the elements that are loaded on a page. Like for example the javascript files, images, and CSS file.

I am wondering if there is a way for me to check this with PHP and output it. 
Would this be possible? Or should I use a third party application for this?

Help and ideas are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot check what is happening client-side from PHP. You need Javascript to benchmark this. There are 3rd party commercial services that do that kind of benchmarking if you include a small snippet in your site…

Comment: If that would not be possible, are there any applications that can help you check this on a website and give a output?

Comment: open your developer console and go to the network tab. reload your page and you should see other files like your css, js and the time they took to load in milli seconds.

Comment: I, of course, know that one but for example a big website with multiple pages. If you want to check the page speed on a recurring base. Like every day or something. Would that not be possible? Like an automation system.

Comment: The most productive is to use some existing analytics service that will gather real world data from visitors for you and present it to you in a nice dashboard.